# How to keep my unity3d program (c# v3.5) even if there is an exit(1) in a c++ dll / native plugin?

Tags: c#, c++, plugins, unity-game-engine, native-code

I use a c++ dll in my unity3d project and if any input is incorrect, the library use exit(1), which makes unity3d crashes/closes. Is there any way to avoid this behavior without modifying the original c++ code ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this would work but try to **call** the **C++** **function** in a **try** and **catch** **clause**. For example:

```
try{
//Call you C++ function from C# here
}catch(Exception e){

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I already catch  SEHException  && ExternalException, without any effect.

Comment: Ok. Never tried it before on C++ plugin and that was a suggestion. Why can't you modify the C++ plugin to remove the exit(1)  code?

Comment: wait @LBarret ... did you try in `finally` ??